# Vb.net: Recording multiple Indexes of pattern in a large string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, search, indexof

I'm currently stuck on a project where I am given a large random string such as: "  C   AF   EE D  D B EE   F" (Could be 900+ chars) and I have to get the index of multiple instances of a pattern, then have them stored into a dynamic array.

Like I need the index's of the pattern "EE", which should be 8 and 18 (I think?). I then need these indexes recorded in a dynamic array like "EE_Array()"

I found this code:

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim EE_Array() As String
    Dim SearchWithinThis As String = "  C   AF   EE   D B EE   F"
    Dim SearchForThis As String = "EE"
    Dim First As Integer = SearchWithinThis.IndexOf(SearchForThis)
    Dim Array(i) = First
```

Then I repeat the code doing a search for another pattern storing it in another array.

Which works GREAT, but only for the first instance. I need to put this in a loop and have increment i and redim Preserve the array making it bigger and keep going till it hits the end of the string (which I think is -1).

Comment: You need a loop. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

Comment: Ya, a loops the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SearchWithinThis As String = "  C   AF   EE   D B EE   F"
    Dim SearchForThis As String = "EE"

    Dim Indexes As List(Of Integer) = GetIndexes(SearchWithinThis, SearchForThis)

    Dim EE_Array() As Integer = Indexes.ToArray
End Sub

Private Function GetIndexes(ByVal SearchWithinThis As String, ByVal SearchForThis As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim Result As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim i As Integer = SearchWithinThis.IndexOf(SearchForThis)

    While (i <> -1)
        Result.Add(i)
        i = SearchWithinThis.IndexOf(SearchForThis, i + 1)
    End While

    Return Result
End Function
```

the function GetIndexes returns a list of integers containing the indexes

Comment: This is PERFECT. I may be able to just use the list and not bother with the extra step of the array. :)

Comment: But what if I wana search for say "EE" and then single instances of every individual "E" adding them to "EE_Array"? Currently I would have to run the function twice but append to the same list. Is there a way to pipe in multiple search criteria?